# How to send HTTPS request from GAE servlet?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, https

I'm trying to send https request using GAE technologies. But if I use

```
HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
```

it will crash

> java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   com.google.apphosting.utils.security.urlfetch.URLFetchServiceStreamHandler$Connection
>   cannot be cast to javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection

If I change `HttpsURLConnection` to `HttpURLConnection`, everything will work ok, but I don't think https advantages will be used. So how can I send https request properly?

Comment: Is it helpful for you? https://cloud.google.com/appengine/kb/general?hl=en#https and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5367974/https-only-in-google-app-engine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume, that `obj` is of `java.net.URL` type.
Simply, you should not use `javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection` in this case.

`URL#openConnection()` method returns type `java.net.URLConnection`, and does not provide almost any guarantees on it subtypes (apart of weird javadoc description, see below*), and Google makes use of it.
Your application should not rely on specifics of `HttpsURLConnection`. There are two options:

- use only `URLConnection` - guaranteed by API,
- use `HttpURLConnection` as `URLFetchServiceStreamHandler$Connection` extends it, and it is unlikely to be changed.

In both cases, HTTPS features will be used; casting does not change the nature of the object.

Other case are client certificates in GAE - see [Client Authentication by Certificate in GAE java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20239163/client-authentication-by-certificate-in-gae-java) queston.

*Weird thing is, that javadoc for `URL.openConnection` says:

> If for the URL's protocol (such as HTTP or JAR), there exists a public, specialized URLConnection subclass belonging to one of the following packages or one of their subpackages: java.lang, java.io, java.util, java.net, the connection returned will be of that subclass. For example, for HTTP an HttpURLConnection will be returned, and for JAR a JarURLConnection will be returned.

(source: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#openConnection)

HttpsConnction is not in any of mentioned packages, so Google is free to provide any type it wants to. But such description gives a possibility to add `HttpsURLConnection` in the future to - for example - `java.util` package, and then AppEngine implementation will be no longer relevant. This is only speculation, and most probably it will never happen - but there is no guarantee! :)

Answer (score 0):

HttpURLConnection works for me